# Can I Develop Ionic app for Windows Phone

Tags: ionic-framework

I m using **Ionic 1.3** and **Cordova 6.0** can i Develop Apps for Windows phone and Blackberry Phones?

If Yes what are the prerequisites and Steps?

Answer (score 3):

We cannot develop Windows App using Ionic version 1. In the same time Ionic Version 2 is now supporting for Windows Application development. You can get more details from the below official blog post.

http://blog.ionic.io/announcing-windows-support-in-ionic-2/

Answer (score 0):

Windows app development via Ionic platform is available in Ionic version 2, however, be advised, it's a beta release.

http://blog.ionic.io/announcing-windows-support-in-ionic-2/